# button link to a page where read more function should be executed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two files. In the file index.html there is a text and with the read more button you can read more. There is a button in the index2.html file that links to the index.html file.
Now I want that when you get from index2.html to the index.html page you can read the whole text, that means that you don't have to press the read more button first to read the whole text.

index.html

```
<style>
    .toggle-text {
        display: none;
    }
    .btn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }
</style>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /*global $ */
    $(document).on("click", ".toggle-text-button", function () {

    if ($(this).text() === "read more") {
        $(this).text("read less");
        $(".toggle-text-" + $(this).attr("toggle-text")).slideDown();
    } else {
        $(this).text("read less");
        $(".toggle-text-" + $(this).attr("toggle-text")).slideUp();
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>this is a test</p>

    <div class="toggle-text toggle-text-1">
        <p>show when click on the button</p>
    </div>

    <a class="toggle-text-button btn" toggle-text="1">read more</a>
</body>
```

index2.html

```
<head>

    <style></style>
    
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        /*global $ */
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".toggle-text-load").on("click", function () {
        $("#toggle-text-1").load("index.html");

        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    
    <a href="\index.html" class="toggle-text-load btn" toggle-text="1">link to other file</a>
    
</body>
```

the error is in the index2.html file. I don't know exactly how to write the function so that the text in "slideDown" is due.
Many thanks for the help!

Comment: iframe? oh, and use / in href not \ - microsoft didn't invent the internet

Comment: You are not actually _navigating_ to the index.html here, you are using AJAX to load it in the background, and then insert it into the _current_ page. The `load` method takes a callback function as third parameter, so you should probably do it from within there.